# Import image with Odoo API in Python 3.4

Tags: python, base64, odoo

I'm working on a script to import a list of product in my Odoo database. The script is working really fine with the Odoo API, except for importing the image.
What I have done so far, is to import an image from an URL in python, and then, encoding it in base64:

```
    response = requests.get(image_url)
    img_obj = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    buffer = BytesIO()
    img_obj.save(buffer, format="JPEG")
    img = base64.encodestring(buffer.getvalue()).strip()
    try:
        base64.b64decode(img)
    except TypeError:
        padding = len(img) % 4
        if padding == 1:
            img = "Invalid base64 string: {}".format(img)
        elif padding == 2:
            img += b'=='
        elif padding == 3:
            img += b'='
```

This code is working great. But, when I run the python code to import it with Odoo API, here is what I have:

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: Fault 1: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 56, in xmlrpc_return
 result = openerp.http.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 114, in dispatch_rpc
 result = dispatch(method, params)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 37, in dispatch
 res = fn(db, uid, *params)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 173, in execute_kw
 return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
 return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 181, in execute
 res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 170, in execute_cr
 return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 238, in wrapper
 return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/addons/stock/product.py", line 518, in write
 return super(product_template, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 238, in wrapper
 return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 369, in old_api
 result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/addons/account/models/product.py", line 45, in write
 res = super(ProductTemplate, self).write(vals)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
 return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 562, in new_api
 result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/addons/product/product.py", line 705, in write
 res = super(product_template, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 238, in wrapper
 return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 369, in old_api
 result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 274, in write
 result = super(MailThread, self).write(values)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
 return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3820, in write
 self._write(old_vals)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
 return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 562, in new_api
 result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3971, in _write
 result += self._columns[field].set(cr, self, id, field, vals[field], user, context=rel_context) or []
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 646, in set
 'datas': value,
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 236, in wrapper
 return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 478, in new_api
 result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py", line 459, in create
 values['mimetype'] = self._compute_mimetype(values)
 File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py", line 252, in _compute_mimetype
 mimetype = guess_mimetype(values['datas'].decode('base64'))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 503, in decode
 self.data = base64.decodestring(data)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 321, in decodestring
 return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
Error: Incorrect padding
```

I have tried to correct the base64 padding, (as you can see in my previous code), but that's not working. Did anyone know how can I fixe this problem?
May it come from my script, which is in Python 3.4 wheras Odoo is in Python 2.7 ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please get your traceback properly formatted!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finaly find out the problem.
As I was wondering, the problem come from the difference between Python 3.4 et Python 2.7.
I just run my code in python 2.7, changing just some library importation, and now, it's work :-)

Hope this could help someone!